# Configure Gradle Dependencies In Different Files

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using external dependencies.gradle file that is place in the same directory where build.gradle (Project) is placed.I am using following command

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'
```

**dependencies.gradle**

```
ext {
SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION = '28.0.0'
dependencies = [
        ANNOTATIONS: "com.android.support:support-annotations:$SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION"
]}
```

**build.gradle (App)**

```
api rootProject.ext.dependencies.ANNOTATIONS
```

above code working perfectly fine. I want to know about how may I exclude group or module using same approach?
let me write the point where i am stuck

```
dependencies = [
        espresso: ("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2") {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        }
]
```

I am getting this error

```
No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (dependencies_83n19kvhft5hx8evun34kydx1$_run_closure1$_closure2) values: [dependencies_83n19kvhft5hx8evun34kydx1$_run_closure1$_closure2@759d33fd] Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), take(int), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude some data, you need to do it in your `build.gradle` file:

**dependencies.gradle**

```
dependencies = [
    espresso: "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2"
]
```

**build.gradle**

```
testImplementation(rootProject.ext.dependencies.espresso) {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

Because `implementation(object) { //Closure... }` is a method with 2 params: Object and Action. You can see [this doc.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/language/ComponentDependencies.html#implementation-java.lang.Object-org.gradle.api.Action-)

Answer (score 0):

Your "dependencies" it is array of strings, not dependencies. Your exception throwed on add closure (groovy lambda) to String type

This:

```
   {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
```

worked only for dependency. You can add exclude only from dependencies {} block

Try to create **espresso.gragle**

```
apply from: "$rootDir/dependencies.gradle"

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation(
        rootProject.ext.dependencies.ESPRESSO {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        }
    )
}
```

Next add to your **build.gradle (App)**

```
apply from: "$rootDir/espresso.gradle"
```

I also recommend add dependencies to your module like this:

**dependencies.gradle**

```
ext.libs = [:]

def versions = [:]
versions.support = "28.0.0"

def libs = [:]

def support = [:]
support.annotations = "com.android.support:support-v4:$versions.support"
support.another = "com.android.support:another:$versions.support"
// another support dependencies
libs.support = support

ext.libs = libs
```

**build.gradle (App)**

```
apply from: "$rootDir/dependencies.gradle" // path to dependencies.gradle

dependencies(
    api(
        libs.support.annotations,
        libs.support.another
    )
)
```